# Handling the Promise from a Popup window eventListener

Tags: angularjs, popup, ionic-framework, addeventlistener, angular-promise

I want to handle the promise of a callback from the 'loadstop' eventListener. I've tried a few things but I continue to get "undefined" from Angular when I try accessing the promise. Is this possible?

```
        win = window.open(login_url, '_blank', 'location=no,toolbar=no');
        //
        // Since Cordova does not support window to window messaging, we need to use this somewhat hacky method
        // to catch the results of the popup window every time the page is done loading.
        //

        var promise = new $q.promise(_extractBootstrapToken);
        win.addEventListener('loadstop', promise);

        promise.then(function(bootstrapToken) {
            deferred.resolve(bootstrapToken);
        });
```

Comment: I've tried various ways, using $on/$emit/$broadcast and $watch and nothing seems to work properly. I want to internally track when the callback is done with its work and react to the encapsulating promise.